# PowerShell script to delete Windows profiles fails to get proper timestamp

Tags: powershell, user-profiles

Note: I cannot do this by GPO, as my group has no control over that. DelProf2 has the same issues with timestamps.

I wrote a script to delete old profiles, due to the drives on multiuser devices getting filled up. The issue as best I see it that Windows or some other process is modifying the LastUseTime so that all profiles have the same stamp.

```
# Prompt the user for the number of days
$days = Read-Host "Enter the number of days to keep profiles"

# Define the list of users to protect
$protected_users = @("administrator","all users","default","default user","public")

# Get a list of all user profiles
$profiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Directory

# Loop through each profile and delete if it's older than the specified number of days
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    $username = $profile.Name
   $last_write = $profile.LastUseTime
    $age = New-TimeSpan -Start $last_write -End (Get-Date)
    
    # Skip the profile if it belongs to a protected user
    if ($protected_users -contains $username) {
        Write-Host "Skipping protected user profile: $username"
        continue
    }
    
    # Delete the profile if it's older than the specified number of days
    if ($age.TotalDays -ge $days) {
        Write-Host "Deleting user profile: $username"
       Remove-Item -Path $profile.FullName -Recurse -Force
    }
}
# Exit and delete the script
Read-Host "Press any key to exit..."
```

Comment: I don't think this question is well-phrased. Well, if there was a question in the 1st place. Do you want to find out what's changing the `LastUseTime`, change the script to something more reliable, or?

Comment: Either way will work. If there is a way to update the `LastUseTime` to the last actual login time before running this, or if there is another way to find the true last login time.

Comment: I think you should check the `LastWriteTime` for the `ntuser.dat` file (HKCU registry data) within each folder: `gci c:\users -ad | %{ $HKCULastWrite = (gi "$($_.FullName)\ntuser.dat" -Force).LastWriteTime ; [PSCustomObject]@{'FolderPath' = $_.FullName ; 'HKCULastWrite' = $HKCULastWrite ; 'Age' = (New-TimeSpan -Start $HKCULastWrite -End (Get-Date)).Days}}`

Comment: The date for the user folder and `ntuser.dat` gets set to the current date. I just signed into a device that has been on the shelf for a while and all those dates are tody.